# Is the name of template folder in Django required all lower case?

Tags: python, django

I'm currently start learning Django after some python basics. When I configure my template dir like this, the app can't file the template folder and files:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "/home/hoangtu/Aptana\ Studio\ 3\ Workspace/django_bookmarks/Template",            
)
```

I have to rename the folder to lower case ("templates"), and it magically works!

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "/home/hoangtu/Aptana\ Studio\ 3\ Workspace/django_bookmarks/templates",            
)
```

Is that true or am I missing something?

*Edit*: And of course, I change the folder name appropriate to the folder name in the path.

Comment: I don't know if you cut/paste it, or typoed - but your example went from `Template` to `templates`, which is spelled differently (an added *s*).

Answer (score 0):

Did you also rename the folder itself, or only changed the config entry?

It shouldn't matter what the folder name is, as long as the name is consistent with the configuration. *nix systems see a difference between "templates" and "Templates", but both should work when configured properly.

Comment: I keep getting TemplateDoesNotExist if I rename the folder (and of course - the path in setting.py as well) with one of the upper case character. With all lower case, it runs fine.